# How does copy collector in java manages to skip dead objects from visting?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand how copy collector in java works. But it seems to be bit confusing that the advantage of copy collector is, it skips the visit to all the object that are supposed to be collected and moves live object to other half of heap. So my question is how does gc then calls finalize on dead objects without visiting them or does that not count for as  visiting object?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that most objects will not have a finalize method and Java can optimize for that case. I seem to remember that objects with finalize methods are actually treated differently (i.e. on a slower path) than other objects.

Comment: @JoachimSauer When an object with a `finalise()` method is created, alongside it the VM creates a `FinalizerReference` object too, pointing to it. And once the object is unreachable by other means, that reference is put in the finalizer queue, which has a single thread as its consumer, so if lots of objects are queuing, it will take a considerable time to process it. It might even mean that the GC is forced to move the object to the old generation, making things even worse. Without a finaliser and any other non-strong references the VM can happily mark the object as unreachable straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion is with the definition of "visiting".

Initially all objects need to be "visited" and the ones unreachable through strong references put in various internal queues (see weak/soft/phantom references), including the finalizer queue.

All throughout this process the object is still considered reachable, and thus not collectable by the GC. (Indeed one of the problems with finalizers is that it is possible to accidentally revive a dying object.) Once the object goes through all these queues, only then is it considered fully reclaimable.

What that statement means is that once all of the above is out of the way, the copy collector doesn't need to re-visit them, just copy the live objects (including those still in the finalizer queue) to the survivor space and leave the rest behind.

This stands in comparison with a compacting collector, which has to check through the entire heap, find where the gaps are and try to minimize them by working out which live object best fits in the gaps (obviously the actual algorithm will be more clever than that :)).

The tradeoff here is that with a copy collector you can only ever use half of the heap and you have to copy all live objects, even if there were no gaps. What you get in return is a fully compacted heap, which is good for fast allocation and caching.

All of the above make the copy collector ideally suited for young generation collection, while compacting collectors were traditionally used for the tenured generation.

---

As an interesting aside, the G1 collector introduced in Java 7 provides a different approach: in this system the heap is split into many equal size regions and tries to identify which regions contain mostly garbage, prioritizing them for copying.

Comment: But then isn't mark and compact does the same thing it will  only move objects that are alive, and finalize queue is different than visiting, I think that doesn't count here to as visit too.

Comment: @Shanky I added some more detail on the difference